# Applying LASSO with cross-sectional/time-series data

Tags: regression, time-series, model-selection, panel-data, lasso

Even after reading the original paper on LASSO, I am still confused as to how to apply LASSO for variable selection when the response variable *y*  is a matrix (and not a vector) of *n* dependent variables with *t* observations each.

As an example, the response variable *y* is monthly household consumption for 50 households over 12 months, while the predictors are price of basket of goods, income...

Should LASSO be done for each household over the 12 months, and the models for all households be averaged after that? Or should LASSO be applied across households for each month, then the models be averaged for all months?